# Exception unexpected token: SMALLINT; while AUTOINCREMENTing PRIMARY KEY

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, ucanaccess

Following is my piece of code. But when I execute following exception is generated.
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: unexpected token: SMALLINT

```
   String sql= "CREATE TABLE "+emailId.getText()+"Inbox (id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,fromId varchar(50), InMsgs varchar(200))";
   Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
   con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://path/Email.accdb");
            st=con.createStatement();
            con.setAutoCommit(false);

            check2=st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

I'm using MSAccess database, Java SE 8 in netbeans with UCanAccess 2.0.9.4.
What is the problem

Comment: What if you do `id AUTOINCREMENT`?

Comment: without integer? @shmosel

Comment: If I use `id Primary Key AUTOINCREMENT` then I get `unexpected token :Primary` as exception  @shmosel

Comment: But that's not what I said.

Comment: What does it mean without integer? @shmosel

Comment: I'm not sure. But what's the harm in trying?

Comment: Try `id COUNTER PRIMARY KEY, ...`.

Comment: It creates the table. But when I try to open it I get the error: " Reserved error(-5001);there is no message for this error  " @Gord Thompson

Comment: @Ticktick please try `id  AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ` there is no need to specify integer..AUTOINCREMENT is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like this

```
CREATE TABLE "+emailId.getText()+"Inbox 
(id AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
fromId varchar(50), 
InMsgs varchar(200))
```

AUTOINCREMENT is already specified so no need for 'Integer'. Also `Primary Key`  key word should come after the datatype.

Comment: It creates the table. But when I try to open it I get the error: " Reserved error(-5001);there is no message for this error "

Comment: @Ticktick did u tried the same query from msaccess? Just try and check the result..also post the full query you tried.

Comment: @Ticktick any space in table name creating?

Comment: which version  of msaccess is using?

Comment: MSAccess 2007 and no, No spaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104085/discussion-between-sachu-and-ticktick).

Comment: @Ticktick try to download latest UcanAccess [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/files/latest/download)